# python subprocess qsub command in multiprocessing environment

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing, qsub

I have a list of commands that I need to run though a lsf farm (using `"qsub -I"`). 
Lets say the commands are listed in commands_l. I am using multiprocessing module trying to run 2 processes at a time. (I am using linux)

Here is the code:

```
import subprocess, multiprocessing
import os,sys,os.path

def execCmd(cmd):
  """ Executes the command """
  print "Executing:",cmd
  ret = subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
  return ret

if __name__=="__main__":
  commands_l = ['qsub -P test -I ls -l', 'qsub -P test -I df -kh', 'qsub -P test -I du -kh .']

  results_l = []
  errorcodes_l = []
  max_proc = 2
  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=max_proc)
  for command in commands_l:
    print "# %s" % (command)
    errorcode = pool.apply_async(execCmd, (command,), callback=results_l.append)
    errorcodes_l.append(errorcode)
  pool.close()
  pool.join()
  print "Results:", results_l
  sys.exit(0)
```

The problem I'm facing is that execution gets stuck with output:

```
# qsub -P test -I ls -l
# qsub -P test -I df -kh
# qsub -P test -I du -kh .
Executing: qsub -P test -I ls -l
Executing: qsub -P test -I df -kh
Job <1683534> is submitted to queue <q_interactive>.
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
Job <1683535> is submitted to queue <q_interactive>.
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
<<Starting on machine-23>>
<<Starting on machine-20>>
```

The strange thing is that when I run execCmd alone with the same command "qsub -P test -I ls -l" it works fine.

```
>>> import multiprocess_qsub # my py file that contains the abovementioned code
>>> multiprocess_qsub.execCmd("qsub -P test -I ls -l")
Executing: qsub -P test -I ls -l
Job <1687635> is submitted to queue <q_interactive>.
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
<<Starting on machine-02>>
total 3
-rwx------  1 tully user 2959 Jul  5 14:54 functions.py
-rwx------  1 tully user 906  Jun 27 23:06 gui.py
-rw-------  1 tully user 1684 Jul 13 14:24 multiprocess_qsub.py
```

It seems to me that qsub has some problem in running from within the multiprocessing environment. Am I missing something? Thanks.